# How to get path to add number of Images that are in the resource to be displayed in the WebView in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, webview, nsbundle

I am added image to my application but I want to display them into my web view. I tried but not succeeded. how can I set the path for those images in html in image tag and how to display them.

Please help me out of this.

Thank you,
Madan Mohan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just displaying the images individually or do you have an HTML file that references them?

To get a URL to the files directly:

```
NSString *pathForImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathForImage];
```

If you're loading an HTML file that references the images (such as by including an `<img src="image.png">`, with no path info) then:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString
    baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

EDIT: so, supposing you had image.png in your application bundle as a resource, then you could do:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:@"<html><body><img src=\"image.png\"></body></html>"
    baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

Comment: NSURL may not respond to fileUrlWithPath is showing as warning

Comment: Sorry, typo in the original code. Until a second ago I had NSURL *URL = [URL fileURLWithPath:pathForImage], which was attempting to call an instance method on an uninitialised object. Obviously the 'URL' should be 'NSURL' — it's a class method as defined at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath: and I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Where this URL supposed to be used

Comment: To be honest, I misread your question. I think you probably want the second suggestion — set the web view's base URL to your application's resource URL and then references to images should work.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML for the webview do

`<img src="imagename">`

Where imagename is the filename of the image. The iPhone doesn't have any folder structures or anything like that. That means that even if you have groups or folders set up in XCode, at runtime they are all lumped into one, giant directory.

If that doesn't work right away, look at what your are setting your base url to be. It might be that you need to set the baseURL to nil to remind the phone to look locally.

Comment: Xcode can preserve folders, it just doesn't normally. If you right click 'Resources', go Add... -> Existing Files..., select a directory and change the option 'Recursively create groups for any added folders' to 'Create Folder References for any added folders' then the directory will show up in Xcode as blue, not yellow, and will be copied into your bundle as a directory rather than flattened out. Things in Xcode groups are flattened.

Answer (score 0):

The following code sample might fix the problem for you.. Good luck!

```
NSData * image = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"image.png"];
[self.webView loadData:image MIMEType:@"image/png" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
[image release];
[self.view addSubView:webView];
```

Comment: I am not setting the web view background

Comment: The code i've provided doesn't set the background, it adds an image to the UIWebView, but if you want to do it with HTML then i don't have a good answer for you.. :) i've done it this way..